# Dotted footnote rule

Tags: footnotes, rules

Here is my code to generate a text with a footnote:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,paper=a4,11pt,onecolumn]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
  \kern -4.5pt
  \hrule width \textwidth height 0.5pt
  \kern 4pt
}                   

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This a piece of text with a footnote here\footnote{This is my footnote} for testing purposes.
\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

I need to change the footnote rule that separates my footnote from the main text to a dotted line, keeping the same the other settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for `\leaders`. `\leaders` is a TeX primitive used to repeat a box until it fills some space. I used `\xleaders` here: the `x` stands for "expanded leaders", to ensure the dots are placed aligned with the margins.

I added three customisation points: `\fnoterulesep` is the distance between two consecutive dots, and `\fnoterulechar` is the character to be repeated. Here's an example with `2pt` and `.`:

> [image]

and here with `5pt` and `$\bullet$`:

> [image]

I also added a `\fnoteruleaftersep` to tweak the distance between the rule and the footnotes.

```latex
\documentclass[titlepage,paper=a4,11pt,onecolumn]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newlength\fnoterulesep
\setlength\fnoterulesep{2pt}
\newlength\fnoteruleaftersep
\setlength\fnoteruleaftersep{4pt}
\newcommand\fnoterulechar{.}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
  {\sbox0{\fnoterulechar\kern\fnoterulesep}%
   \par\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip+\ht0+\dp0-\fnoteruleaftersep}%
  \noindent
  \xleaders\hbox{%
    \fnoterulechar
    \kern\fnoterulesep}%
      \hfill\fnoterulechar
  \par \nointerlineskip
  \vspace*{\dimexpr-\ht0-\dp0+\fnoteruleaftersep}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This a piece of text with a footnote here\footnote{This is my footnote} for testing purposes.

\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need to adjust the vertical space the total is supposed to be 0pt, but you have a paragraph with the dots

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks very much!!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed. I fixed it (I think :-). What problem would a non-zero height rule cause?

Comment: @José See the edit. I fixed the definition after David's comment.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik potentially an overfull page  box as the output routine leaves no space for the rule, it is assumed to take zero space

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[titlepage,paper=a4,11pt,onecolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
  \kern -4.5pt
 \vbox to 0.5pt{\hbox to \textwidth{\leaders\hbox{\kern 4pt .\kern 4pt}\hfil}\vss}
  \kern 4pt
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\vspace*{12cm}

\section{Introduction}
This a piece of text with a footnote here\footnote{This is my footnote} for testing purposes.
\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you should force the box height to .5pt (or adjust the vskips to total - the height of a the leaders dot).

Comment: @David Carlisle: do you mean the outer box or the inner box?

Comment: well anything, but the output routine leaves no space for a footnote rule so the rule has to be a construct that adds no vertical space, that's why the original had two vskips totalling -.5pt and a rule of height .5pt

Comment: Your solution also works fine. I will take it as a second option. Thanks very much for you time!!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'm not too sure whether my modification makes the code really talke into account the vertical space 5I'm in no way a TeX specialist…)

Comment: better, thanks:-)

Comment: What should I do if I like to have the dotted footnote rule only for one specific footnote and not for the rest of footnotes in the document?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe you  should post it as a new  question.